# How to Implement "Code Bubble" like User Interface?

Tags: eclipse, ide, user-interface

The new [Code Bubble IDE](http://www.cs.brown.edu/people/acb/codebubbles_site.htm) has been in the news. I wonder if there are useful libraries to implement this kind of interface (for other applications)? I prefer java or python. I understand Code Bubble has been implemented on Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks more like it's implemented in Squeak Smalltalk using it's interface parts as building blocks and Eclipse as back-end.

You can use some sort of good custom drawing library like Piccolo http://www.piccolo2d.org to build your own blocks and connected them together.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I'd like to make it known that there is a plugin called Debug Canvas that that does that.